# What happens to smart contracts when breaking changes are introduced to ink?

Tags: ink, smart-contract, substrate-node, pallet-contracts

I've seen breaking changes mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/issues/1701) for upgrading `set_code_hash`.

This got me thinking, what happens to existing contracts when a breaking change to ink is introduced?

For example, we're currently on ink v4.3.0. Let's say a breaking change is introduced in ink v5. How would my live contract fair when RPC nodes upgrade their `pallet_contracts` pallet to ink v5? Surely this would be a breaking change for my live contract on ink v4? How is this handled?